# DDD User-Domain specific settings

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

I am currently developing micro service responsible for authentication (bounded context responsible for identity and permissions). We have specific settings based on user roles which are tied to another domains, but used to generate tokens

(something like this https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/custom_roles)

For an example

```
role_can_write_booking: true,
fetch_products_type : "all/forUsersCompanyOnly"
```

etc.

Should I persist this information as a part of Identity BC, or each domain should persist it's part of settings.
Example:
`role_can_write_booking : true` inside Booking Bounded Context,
`fetch_products_type : "all/forUsersCompanyOnly"` inside Booking products bounded context. ?

Comment: Just curious... Do you have a lot of roles that span across multiple Bounded Contexts? Can you give an example of such a role? In my experience, each subdomain's Ubiquitous Language tends to define its own personas/role names.

Comment: @guillaume31 each bounded context will present one of functionalities, such as accounting, booking, products etc. One of examples is that we will be able to have agents which are responsible for booking. some may have access to booking and products, etc. Globally speaking, they are all agents, but in the Ubiquitous Language, one will be BookingAgent, one will be ProductAgent. Some of them will be able to read only, some of them will be able to edit etc

Comment: Not being able to give more precise role names than e.g. [Booking+Products responsible] feels like a smell to me. What if roles were really per-BC ? Then again, I'm not in your domain.

Comment: @guillaume31 The idea is to allow flexibility to our clients. I might have employee in my company who will be responsible for Booking and Product Management. He will be BookingAgent in the Booking BC, and ProductManager in the products BC, but then again, another client might decide that ProductManager for his company in our system will be able to Create products, but not delete them, which represents different set of permissions.

Comment: I'm confused. In the end, can a role potentially contain any permisssion from any BC, as your first example suggests? Or is a role defined on a per-BC basis, containing only permissions from a specific BC? IMO that should strongly influence the way you implement the role system.

Comment: @guillaume3 Each company will be able to create roles to suit their needs, but with our predefined set of rules for each BC. They can create one role, name it, add description to it, and decide that role can access booking, create new bookings,cannot delete any bookings, or whatever we decide is required for that BC.

Comment: It's still not clear, but if every role requires defining a value for each permission that ever existed in any BC, you might be strongly inciting your customers to create roughly one role per user in the system. I wouldn't count on the customers for defining roles and role names that are relevant in their domain - they will basically understand roles as a discrete set of permissions and will have difficulty naming them. This is IMO not what Roles (or Groups, or User Types) should be pushing towards.

Comment: @guillaume3 what would be your suggestion to fulfill following requirements : You have a basic client who is more than happy with our predefined roles. For him, ProductAgent presents a person who is responsible for entire products domain, and he's fine with that, we're fine with that. Token for this user will be able to fetch all clients products from our micro-service. Then you have an enterprise client, who decided that token issued for one of his users is capable to fetch only products which he's assigned to, and he can never "abuse" his token, to fetch/see all products for his company.

Comment: I'm not questioning the need for custom roles. The thing is, in both examples you just gave I can only see *Product permissions*, not Booking permissions, which might indicate that your roles are per-BC, not cross-BCs (hence my original question). Defining and storing your roles strictly inside the limits of a Bounded Context may well solve most of the problem, because users wouldn't be tempted to create fat, all-encompassing Roles.

Comment: "This is IMO not what Roles (or Groups, or User Types) should be pushing towards." What should Roles and Groups push towards if not describing authorization rules?

Comment: By "this" I meant ad-hoc sets of permissions where almost every individual user has their own custom combination of privileges. This defeats the whole purpose of Roles. My feeling is that the more BCs your roles span over, the more disparate your permission sets will be and the more you will stray towards that misuse of Roles. But I may be wrong, that's why I asked for examples of legit cross-BC roles :)

Comment: @guillaume31 I understand your point. I appreciate feedback very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. There are trade-offs either way. If you store all the information inside the identity context then it needs to have knowledge of all the other contexts and needs to change whenever some permission or access rule changes in any context. If each context manages its own permission rules then they only need to know about themselves.

You also need to consider how things are managed. Is there a concept of centrally managing roles and permissions?

It also depends on how course or fine-grained the roles need to be and how complex the domain is in terms of identity / roles / permissions etc.

If you have very course-grained roles (I.e. 'Administrator', 'User') then I'd probably do something along the lines of having the identity context manage user accounts and roles, but leave the permissions side of things to each individual context. I.e 'here's an authenticated user with roles X and Y' then each individual context determines what this allows.